# web scraping full img src from dynamic website using Perl

Tags: perl, web-scraping, dynamic-content

I'm using the Perl Web::Scraper module to fetch an img src from a Zazzle product page which is the result of an API call.

If I use a web browser to view page source, the image has a full path (from the ? onwards). When I retrieve the HTML using a Perl script (I also tried File::Fetch), I only get until ".jpg".

Browser Page Source produces this img src:

http://rlv.zcache.com/coat_of_arms_t_shirt-rb35fa7573d9448a4aeed82f56d98c523_j2nhl_512.jpg?t_supporters_iid=18c7f0d0-5bf8-4aa5-b6b8-5151099cc0ad

Perl script retrieves this img src:

http://rlv.zcache.com/coat_of_arms_t_shirt-rb35fa7573d9448a4aeed82f56d98c523_j2nhl_512.jpg

Is it possible to retrieve the full src from this kind of website using a Perl script?

Here is the Perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use URI;
use Web::Scraper;

my $api_call = "http://www.zazzle.com/api/create/at-238543087866915480?rf=238543087866915480&ax=linkover&pd=235262722863405468&fwd=productpage&ed=true&supporters=http%3A%2F%2Fcoadb-dev.com%2Fwp-content%2Fprocessed_images%2Firvine%2Ffull_size%2Firvine-arms-1.png";

my $image_scraper = scraper {

    process ".ZazzleWidgetsSppMainView-realviewCrop", "images[]" => scraper {

        process "img", src => '@src';

    };
};

my $res = $image_scraper->scrape(URI->new($api_call));

for my $img (@{$res->{images}}) {

    print $img->{src}  . "\n";

}
```

Comment: My solution was installing WWW::Scripter with WWW::Scripter::Plugin::JavaScript and Web::Scraper for processing the returned content.

Comment: ^ Would you add that as an answer below, Jonathan? You can then click the adjacent tick mark to set this question as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was installing WWW::Scripter with WWW::Scripter::Plugin::JavaScript (and Web::Scraper for processing the returned content).

The above plugins were able to access the dynamically generated content from the Javascript. No additional modules were needed.

Thank you!